# HDFS small file design

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, avro, parquet

I want to be able to store millions of small files (binary files- images,exe etc) (~1Mb) on HDFS, my requirements are basically to be able to query random files and not running MapReduce jobs.
The main problem for me is the Namenode memory issue, and not the MapReduce mappers issue.

So my options are:

1. HAR files - aggregate small files and only than saving them with their har:// path in another place
2. Sequence files - append them as they come in, this is more suitable for MapReduce jobs so i pretty much eliminated it
3. HBase - saving the small files to Hbase is another solution described in few articles on google

i guess i'm asking if there is anything i missed? can i achieve what i need by appeding binary files to big Avro/ORC/Parquet files? and then query them by name or by hash from java/client program?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you append multiple files into large files, then you'll need to maintain an index of which large file each small file resides in. This is basically what Hbase will do for you. It combines data into large files, stores them in HDFS and uses sorting on keys to support fast random access. It sounds to me like Hbase would suit your needs, and if you hand rolled something yourself, you may end up redoing a lot of work that Hbase already does.